# Using php preg_replace to replace url with ../

Tags: php

i need replace css : ex: `background: url('../image/abc.png');`

can i using Regular Expressions to replace this like

```
background: url('view/theme/image/abc.png');
```

replace `"url('../image/abc.png')"` to `url('view/theme/image/abc.png');`

thank for help !!

Comment: Yes you can use regex.

Comment: `str_replace("url('../image/", "url('view/theme/image/", $input)`. Possibly you don't need regex.

Comment: thank Jon , so i can using regex for this solution !! one question , which regex and str_replace how which faster ?